# Laravel email conditional send - checking when last email of this type was sent to a user

Tags: php, laravel, email

I run a scheduled task each day to send emails to customers who have outstanding invoice and need to add a condition to check whether the email has been sent to this customer within the last 72 hours.

I guess I would need to:

- Send the mail.
- Log the message type and user to the database
- Check the database for when the last mail was sent.

I have done a fair bit of reading and wonder if anything like this is already included in Laravel? I have not been able to find much so far.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't built in to the platform, but it should be fairly straightforward to add. Sending an email using Laravel's mail functions [triggers a `MessageSent` event](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mail#events). Attach a listener to that event and you can do whatever you like with it. The event will include the message object as well as any data passed to it.

Comment: Thanks. I assume I will need to create a mail logs table as the bare minimum? No way to do it without another table?

Comment: @AdamLambert Only you can answer that question. Maybe you've already got some sort of `actions` or `tracking` table in place that could be used. I wouldn't go stuffing it in the `users` one.